# iOS: Strange cell behaviour in table view when switching back to non-edit (after changing contentinset because of keyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some custom views with embedded table views in them. So I had to program the whole scrolling up etc when the keyboard appears myself. I've used the apple docs for that and came up with this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                   name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                   name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // keyboard frame is in window coordinates
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    // convert own frame to window coordinates, frame is in superview's coordinates
    CGRect ownFrame = [self.tableView.window convertRect:self.tableView.frame fromView:self.tableView.superview];

    // calculate the area of own frame that is covered by keyboard
    CGRect coveredFrame = CGRectIntersection(ownFrame, keyboardFrame);

    // now this might be rotated, so convert it back
    coveredFrame = [self.tableView.window convertRect:coveredFrame toView:self.tableView.superview];

    // set inset to make up for covered array at bottom
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, coveredFrame.size.height, 0);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
}
```

But now the not so nice thing about this (and another code I've tried, same results) is: When scrolling around the table and switching back to non-edit mode, some cells which where hidden before at the bottom of the table are immediately in the non-edit mode and not transitioning back from the indented state. Very rarely this results even in an error, that one cell remains in edit mode even though all cells have been switched back. This error disappears if I scroll the cell away and back and then it's in the correct format.

Any idea why? I've definitely narrowed it down to this code. When I comment everything out it works as it should (well of course without the scrolling when the keyboard appears :-)

Comment: This sounds like a cell dequeue issue. The tableview loads cells based on visibility on screen. Maybe the rect shifting in your code is confusing that. Try updating your tableview when you switch edit mode off.

Comment: just when ending edit mode? and with what method call, [self.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Yes; try that. If that fixes it, the problem is your tableview handling, not your rect code.

Comment: not working sorry..also with apple's implementation of the scrolling it doesn't work. This usually only happens if some cells were hidden behind my fixed "header" and reappear after the end editing. I really have no clue how to solve this :-(